# C# Windows forms controls lost border?

Tags: c#, winforms

While adding controls to form, suddenly all of the elements lost border and the grey inner gloss shadow which as best example, checkboxes and radio buttons have.

Those now look like this: [image]

Instead of like this: [image]

I couldn't find a solution yet. What properties should i change to get the desired styling? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Probably you have removed the `Application.EnableVisualStyles();` from your main method.

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles(); // Did you remove this line?
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

Comment: As I'm starting a threaded form from .dll, I haven't even have that line. Added now and solved the issue. Thank you so much!